# How to set up SVN to work remotely on mac os?

Tags: networking, svn, router

After many hours of work I made SVN server run on my mac os using Apache and anyone from the local network can access the repository.

But I can't figure out, how to make it accessible remotely from the internet?

When I type in my address bar "localhost/svn" my repository is being shown.

But when I type in my_ip/svn, browser can't connect to the server.

I've set up port forwarding on my router for port 3690 to my local ip, but nothing happens.

How can I make accessible my repository from the internet?

Thanks.

Comment: The svnserve daemon (used when a repository is accessed through the native SVN network protocol svn://) usually listens on port 3690. Apache on the other hand usually listens on port 80 and eventually 443.

Comment: @ilya How can i access my svn server on windows from a mac os??

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick question, are you sure you want to make it accessible through the Web? You can make your SVN accessible through ssh using port 22. Install and start an ssh server on your Mac and you can access your SVN with the following:

```
svn co svn+ssh://your.remote-server.com/home/svn/test
```

Comment: Can you please provide me with more information on configuring SSH on mac?

Comment: @Chris J what will be configuration if my svn url is 'svn://localhost/mysvn'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing SVN through Apache, you will need to forward port 80 on your router.

Comment: Will in this case all web content be forwarded to my computer?
There are multiple computers in the local network.

Comment: If anyone accesses your external IP address on port 80, it will be forwarded to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing at your situation my guesses are:

1) Your router has an ip say: 80.1.1.5
2) Internally you have an ip say: 192.168.0.5

You have port forwarded port 3690 to 192.168.0.5 on your router.

What you need to do then is externally use your external ip rather than your internal ip address.

If I am guessing wrong at what you have setup give a bit more info.